# GraphViz: which graph library to use?

Tags: c++, graphviz

I've just started developing a small C++ program using GraphViz's graph library and noticed there are actually *three* different API's: `libgraph`, `libcgraph` and `libagraph`. WTF?

I would like to know what is the difference between them, which one to use and where to look for API documentation. I have looked at the GraphViz [documentation](http://www.graphviz.org/Documentation.php) and mailing list archives but I've found many broken links, lots of wrong or misleading information and now I'm confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like one should use `libcgraph`, compiling with the flags given by `pkg-config libcgraph --cflags --libs` and including `#include <cgraph.h>`.